# How to store datas while connection is lost?

Tags: c#, python, buffer

I've a client (currently in C#, a python version in progress) which gets computer data such as CPU %, disk space etc. and sends it to a server. I don't know how to manage if my client looses connection with the server. I have to continue collecting information but where to stock them? Just a buffer? Is using a log file a better solution?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you only expect occasional, short-term, connection failures, it's probably sufficient to buffer it in RAM, otherwise I'd buffer to disk. Depends how stable your client is, really. ;)

Comment: I would log it on the drive. RAM is so volatile, you have little control over what happens there if your program malfunctions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a log file on the HDD and put in the last recorded data and time. Then just read it out when needed again.

Comment: Yes but create, delete And manage i/o Can generate bugs... This i Why i've asked this question